# Howto: Display a parameter on a SQL Server Report?

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, reporting-services

I'm creating some reports in Visual Studio BIDS, out of our SQL Analysis Server 2008.
The report works fine, and uses an MDX query with parameters. So far, so good.

The problem is that I would like to display the parameter on the report. For example, I would like to display the 'Month' of the Date parameter, but it shows up on the report like this:

```
[Date].[Month].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00]
```

Not really what I want. How can I display this value as 'January' ? I can't find any function which does this. The only way I see this is possible is to include the date value in the returned fields.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the necessary values in the Select-fields.